# XPath get element value from XML

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

I have below XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <LimitInfoHeader>
            <limitInfo>
                <current>142795</current>
                <limit>49754000</limit>
                <type>API REQUESTS</type>
            </limitInfo>
        </LimitInfoHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <queryAllResponse>
            <result xsi:type="QueryResult">
                <done>true</done>
                <queryLocator xsi:nil="true"/>
                <records xsi:type="sf:sObject">
                    <sf:type>User</sf:type>
                    <sf:Id>005030000040AQeAAM</sf:Id>
                    <sf:Id>005030000040AQeAAM</sf:Id>
                </records>
                <size>1</size>
            </result>
        </queryAllResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to get the value of `<sf:Id>005030000040AQeAAM</sf:Id>` and `<size>1</size>`. Please help here.

Comment: Is it correct that there `2` identical `sf:Id` elements?

Comment: yes, this is correct, we can use any of them.

Comment: Please edit your question, and specify what language/environment you are using.

Answer (score 0):

**Just use these 2 XPath 1.0 expressions**:

For `sf:Id`

```
string((//*[name() = 'sf:Id'])[1])
```

And for `size`:

```
string((//*[name() = 'size'])[1])
```

---

**XSLT 1.0 - based verification**:

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="string((//*[name() = 'sf:Id'])[1])"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="string((//*[name() = 'size'])[1])"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <LimitInfoHeader>
            <limitInfo>
                <current>142795</current>
                <limit>49754000</limit>
                <type>API REQUESTS</type>
            </limitInfo>
        </LimitInfoHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <queryAllResponse>
            <result xsi:type="QueryResult">
                <done>true</done>
                <queryLocator xsi:nil="true"/>
                <records xsi:type="sf:sObject">
                    <sf:type>User</sf:type>
                    <sf:Id>005030000040AQeAAM</sf:Id>
                    <sf:Id>005030000040AQeAAM</sf:Id>
                </records>
                <size>1</size>
            </result>
        </queryAllResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**evaluates the 2 XPath expressions and outputs the results of these evaluations -- and we get the correct, wanted values**:

```
005030000040AQeAAM
1
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use this 2.0 XPath...

```xml
//*:queryAllResponse/*:result/(*:size|*:records/*:Id[1])/string()
```

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote other than it selected the elements instead of the values, so I added `string()` to the xpath.

Comment: Just noticed I didn't account for the default namespace. Updated.